# Excel VBA - Word.Selection issue with 462 error

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was creating an Excel vba to search a keyword in a word document and then return the line above it. Here is the code:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim s As Word.Selection
fileaddress = "C:\XXXXXX"

Set appWrd = New Word.Application
Set docWrd = appWrd.Documents.Open(fileaddress)
Set aRange = docWrd.Range

Do
    aRange.Find.Text = "keyword"
    aRange.Find.Execute Forward:=True
    If aRange.Find.Found Then
        aRange.Select
        Set s = Word.Selection
        s.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, COUNT:=1
        MsgBox s.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
        Set s = Nothing
    End If
Loop While aRange.Find.Found

docWrd.Close
appWrd.Quit

End Sub
```

The code works fine the first time, then in the second time a 462 error appears. I guess the issue is probably with this Word.Selection thing. Any idea forks?

PS: The word file is something like below:

1. Heading style 1

keyword

1.1 Heading style 2

keyword

So the code searches for keyword and then move the cursor one line up from keyword's location and then the msgbox would return "1" and "1.1". However, as I said, the code works fine the first time. I think it is something to do with certain process is not killed in the task manager after the previous run of excel.

**SOLVED**

New code:

```
Sub TEST()

Dim s As Word.Selection
fileaddress = "C:\XXXXXX"

Set appWrd = New Word.Application
Set docWrd = appWrd.Documents.Open(fileaddress)
Set aRange = docWrd.Range

Do
    aRange.Find.Text = "keyword"
    aRange.Find.Execute Forward:=True
    If aRange.Find.Found Then
        aRange.Select
        Set s = appWrd.Selection   '<------- This is the only change!
        s.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, COUNT:=1
        MsgBox s.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
        Set s = Nothing
    End If
Loop While aRange.Find.Found

docWrd.Close
appWrd.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting the expected result if you run it in Word VBA, without creating any Word.Application objects?

Comment: I have used the code below in Word VBA and it works fine.

`Sub TEST()`
`Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range`
`Do`
    `aRange.Find.Text = "keyword"`
    `aRange.Find.Execute Forward:=True`
    `If aRange.Find.Found Then`
        `aRange.Select`
        `Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1`
        `sectionNum = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString`
        `MsgBox sectionNum`  
    `End If`
`Loop While aRange.Find.Found`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
Set s = Word.Selection
```

with

```
Set s = appWrd.Selection
```

The "Word" object does not like to be reused after getting killed (even though it is recreated).

Answer (score 0):

When you mentioned "line above it" I tried checking if the word was in a table or else the sentence. So I compare the words in the document to the keyword then read the row above in the table or the sentence it belongs to, then count backwards until the previous sentence is found.

```
Sub TEST_Line(fileaddress As String, Keyword As String)
   Set appWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set docWrd = appWrd.Documents.Open(fileaddress)
   Set DWords = docWrd.Words
   For Counter = 1 To DWords.Count
      If UCase(Keyword) Like UCase(DWords.Item(Counter)) Then
         If DWords.Item(Counter).Tables.Count > 0 Then
            Row_Ref = DWords.Item(Counter).Rows(1).Index - 1
            Col_Ref = DWords.Item(Counter).Columns(1).Index
            If Row_Ref > 0 Then
               MsgBox DWords.Item(Counter).Tables(1).Columns(Col_Ref).Cells(Row_Ref).Range.Text
            End If
         Else
            aRange = DWords.Item(Counter).Sentences(1)
            Reverse_Counter = Counter - 1
            If Reverse_Counter < 1 Then
               'MsgBox "First Sentence"
            Else
               Do While DWords.Item(Reverse_Counter).Sentences(1) = DWords.Item(Counter).Sentences(1)
               Reverse_Counter = Reverse_Counter - 1
               Loop
               MsgBox DWords.Item(Reverse_Counter).Sentences(1)
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next Counter
   docWrd.Close
   appWrd.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Double E. Please see additional info from the original post.